# Change the font-size of just one x-axis labels in ApexCharts?

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I want to change the font size of just one of the x-axis labels, depending on what day it is (x-axis are days of the week).

ApexCharts allows you to customize the color of each data label, but not the font-size it seems.

Here is my code:

```
xaxis: {
categories: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    position: 'bottom',
        labels: {
    show: true,
        style: {
        colors: ['#53599A', '#53599A', '#53599A', '#53599A', '#53599A', '#53599A', '#53599A'],
        fontSize: '12px',
        fontFamily: 'IBM Plex Sans, sans-serif',
        cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label'
    }
}
```

},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **Labels** inside **yaxis** or **xaxis** object you will found the answer, **how to change the font size in apexcharts chart**

```
yaxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontSize: '8px',
        fontWeight: 500,
      },
    }
  },
```

Or

```
xaxis: {
    type: 'category',
    categories: ['a','b','c'],
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontSize: '8px',
        fontWeight: 500,
      },
    }
  },
```

Comment: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/yaxis/ Thx!